# Is there anyway to change Unity's view shortcuts?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use Unity, Substance Painter, Blender and other similar software. Its exhausting  to work with different shortcuts. For example,In Blender you use middle mouse button to pivot around the object and shift+middle mouse button to pan.
But most of the software I use have options to change the shortcuts.

There aren't any option to change this in Unity(?).
Its different than other software I use, for example right click to orbit is very uncomfortable.

How could i get around this? Every time I open up Unity I slog for a minute because of confusion.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. That said, Unity's setup is the one *I* am comfortable with and it's *Blender* that makes it impossible for me to do anything!

Comment: @Draco18s opinions and preferences ... I wouldn't waste too much time on configuration. Every program has its input method, better get used to them! I often have to switch between Unity, Blender, Maya and PhotoShop .. all are using different ways for zooming and moving. Also be aware that as soon as you manipulate the shortcuts and inputs it becomes way harder to follow tutorials and manuals ;)

Comment: So short answer is `yes theoretically it is possible`. Unity is OpenSource and could be overwritten and changed. You even can write your own Scene View window so you don't have to manipulate source code. But the realistic answer is `No` .. in the time you archive that you better learn to switch between the controls ;)

Comment: Thanks for your opinions. My point is I can switch between controls but i dont like it. I also prefer to follow tutorials by what they do rather than what keys they press. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @derHugo The mouse schema is one thing, the all of the everything else that Blender does is quite another. Quick: on the animation timeline, how do you select keyframes with the mouse?

Comment: @Draco18s If you have a question .. :P Just kidding: The same way you select vertices in the 3D views e.g. using `B` and draw a frame arround them, `Right click` (+`shift` for multible), `C` for continues selection etc in Blender. In Unity it's `left click` instead or simply drag a frame

Comment: @derHugo And why are those keys not Shift and Control like *literally every other piece of software?* That's kind of my point: Blender follows no conventions for anything about its UI. It might be internally consistent, but it's literally backwards relative to everything else. Heck, B shouldn't even be needed at all, I should just be able to click on them.

Comment: I feel bad spamming the poor users question with opinions here. It is `shift` in Blender. I don't know what you compare it to but I know a lot of other programs doing multible selection with only `shift` and not with `ctrl` as e.g. Maya